# SSMS command to disconnect after query has finished

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio, is there any way (for example a SQLCMD command or something) to get the SQL script window to automatically disconnect as soon as the query has finished executing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy one ...

Think about why do you want to do it ? Any specific reasons ?

From [BOL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180202.aspx) :

To change the options for the current queries, click Query Options on the Query menu or the shortcut menu of the SQL Server Query window. Under Execution, click Advanced.

> **Disconnect after the query executes**
>
> When this check box is selected, the connection to SQL Server is terminated after the query completes. This check box is cleared by default.

[image]

Comment: Would love to know how to do this by way of SQL query, so you could do it for only one command instead of all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line `use master` at the bottom of your query window, which will release the connection used by the previous lines.  Then you can do whatever you want to your db, regen, move, backup, etc... without needing to close the query window.  This is quite useful for testing scenarios where you don't want to reload the query window every single iteration.

```
use TestDatabase;

select * from Somewhere
select * from SomewhereElse
selecd * from NowhereInParticular

use master
```